# Why function SUM wont work SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

my SUM() won't add the number of students that are female when I group them by their account_ID

here's the query

```
SELECT
    firstname,
    middlename,
    lastname,
    SUM(
        sex = "Female" && course = "BSCS"
    ) AS BSCS,
    SUM(
        sex = "Female" && course = "BSIT"
    ) AS BSIT,
    SUM(
        sex = "Female" && course = "BSIS"
    ) AS BSIS,
    sex,
    course
FROM
    tbl_temporary
WHERE
    tbl_temporary.sex = "Female"
GROUP BY
    temporary_answers
```

Here is the result 
[Result of the Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N71JO.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Your grouping is very unclear. Please post sample data and expected results.

Comment: i wanted it to be the column BSCS to become 2 since there are 2 females with a course of BSCS

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), or return unpredictable data on older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by the wrong column. If you want number of students enrolled in different courses, you must group by `course` instead of `temporary_answers`

Answer (score -1):

Few problem in query, no need to write `sex = "Female"` as where condition have this `tbl_temporary.sex = "Female"`. and you need to write `if else` for this like `sum(if (course = "BSCS", 1, 0))`. So change query and check. And change **`1`** in if to column name whatever you want

```
SELECT 
   firstname,
   middlename,
   lastname,
   SUM(if (course = "BSCS", 1, 0)) as BSCS,
   SUM(if (course = "BSIT", 1, 0)) as BSIT,
   SUM(if (course = "BSIS", 1, 0)) as BSIS,
   sex,
   course from tbl_temporary 
WHERE tbl_temporary.sex = "Female" GROUP BY temporary_answer
```